# My JavaScript code is telling me I have already declared a variable and cannot read properties of null

Tags: javascript

```
let toggleNavStatus = true;

let toggleNav = function() 
{
let getSidebar = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar");
let getSidebarUl = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar ul");
let getSidebarLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-sidebar a");

if(toggleNavStatus === true)

{
    getSidebarUl.style.visibility = "hidden";
    getSidebar.style.width = "50px";
    getSidebarUl.style.opacity = 0;




    let arrayLength=getSidebarLinks.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        getSidebarLinks[i].style.opacity = "0";
        getSidebarLinks[i].style.visibility = "hidden";

        
    }

    toggleNavStatus = false;
}

else if (toggleNavStatus === false)

{
    getSidebarUl.style.visibility = "visible";
    getSidebar.style.width = "50px";

    let arrayLength=getSidebarLinks.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        getSidebarLinks[i].style.opacity = "0.5";
        
    }

    toggleNavStatus = true;
}
```

}

**The error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'toggleNavStatus' has already been declared
VM634 app.js:278
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading'addEventListener')**

Comment: That code will not have the `toggleNavStatus` problem you describe, since `toggleNavStatus` is only declared once. Are you repeatedly pasting this code into the browser console or similar? Because if so, when you paste it a second time, you're redeclaring `toggleNavStatus` (on most consoles; Chrome recently changed theirs to try to help with that).

Comment: [This question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) explain the `null` error.

Comment: I didn't paste it on console . what of the second error ? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading'addEventListener')

Comment: Did you not see my second comment?

Comment: Re `toggleNavStatus`, again, the code in the quesition will not have that "Identifier 'toggleNavStatus' has already been declared" error. Look outside that code to find where you've declared `toggleNavStatus` a second time.

Answer (score 1):

Propose you remove most of your JS code and replace it by using CSS styles and toggling class. It will grant better perfomance and easier to understand.
ex.
On button click (or any other trigger) you are toggling active class on menu:

```
function toggleNav() {
  const sidebar = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar");
  sidebar.classList.toggle('visible');
}
```

And add this CSS:

```
.nav-sidebar {
  width: 50px;
}

.nav-sidebar ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav-sidebar a {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav-sidebar.visible ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-sidebar.visible a {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```